# Can I use the bulk upload option to assign mobile workers to multiple locations?

Tags: commcare

I am migrating several mobile workers to a locations structure and need to assign each mobile worker to a set of assigned locations from the organization structure.

In the mobile worker bulk upload excel file it appears that there is only one field for entering the mobile worker's location ("location_code 1"). Is it possible to add or modify fields in this export that will enable assigning mobile workers to multiple locations using bulk upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My technique has been:

1. Use the web interface to add locations to one specific user so that they've got more assigned locations than you'll most likely use in reality (maybe a test user)
2. Download your bulk mobile user file
3. There will now be more than enough location columns to handle the locations you need to assign.
4. Fill in columns as needed and then upload